# Using YouTube Content ID API with PHP Library and getting 404 on their upload API endpoint

Tags: php, api, youtube, youtube-api

I am using the YouTube Content ID API with their PHP Client Library. I have enabled the API in my console, and am using a YouTube Partner account.

```
$youtubePartner = new Google_Service_YouTubePartner($client);
$asset = new Google_Service_YouTubePartner_Asset();
$metadata2 = new Google_Service_YouTubePartner_Metadata();
$metadata2->{mymetadata};
$asset->setMetadata($metadata2);
$asset->setType("web");

$assetInsertResponse = $youtubePartner->assets->insert($asset);
```

There's some other stuff after involving policy and ownership, but it seems to be failing at this point:

```
Caught Google service Exception 404 message is Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/partner/v1/assets: (404)
```

If I hit that URL in my browser, I get a response (requires Auth). I've authorized everything correctly (it would give a different error message).

I'm using the YouTubePartner.php from https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/client_libraries

Why would I be getting a 404 even though the URL is there? Is there something weird about this library or am I doing something fundamentally wrong here?

Comment: You need to be using v3 of the API.  v1 and v2 have been deprecated.  Docs [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/).

Comment: Are you sure? Because if you look at the ContentID API it shows the v1 link. https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/docs/v1/assets/insert

Comment: Yeah, just tried hitting v3 instead and receieved:
     Caught Google service Exception 404 message is Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/partner/v3/assets: (404)

Answer (score 1):

You should add onBehalfofContentOWner parameter in your requests. Here are samples: https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/code_samples/php

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had that in originally and was getting errors with the ContentOwnerID needing a Channel ID. I don't see in the API how to pull the Channel ID. 

`$contentOwnersListResponse = $youtubePartner->contentOwners->listContentOwners(array('fetchMine' => true));
                    $contentOwnerId = $contentOwnersListResponse['items'][0]['id'];
$insertRequest = $youtube->videos->insert("status,snippet", $video,array('onBehalfOfContentOwner' => $contentOwnerId));`

Comment: That gives me the following error: Failed to start the resumable upload (HTTP 403: youtube.common, For this request the authenticated user must resolve to a channel, but does not. If your request is authenticated and uses the onBehalfOfContentOwner delegation parameter, then you should also set the onBehalfOfContentOwnerChannel parameter.)

Must the YouTube account have a Channel associated with it? If so, how can I obtain the Channel ID via the API?

Comment: Actually, I was able to get the Channel ID via the API (missed that before). But now it's returning the following error: 
`Caught Google service Exception 403 message is Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/partner/v1/assets?onBehalfOfContentOwner={mycontentownerid here}: (403)`

Comment: Were you ever able to get this to work? Having the same problem.